# How to run a django project?

Tags: django

I have just downloaded some Django samples from Github, but I cannot find "manage.py" in them so I could run the server.
does anyone have any idea about how to run this kind of projects? PLEASE ..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuUOX.png)

Comment: Official Django tutorial is a good place to start - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: I have read the whole thing, "manage.py" is the command-line utility that lets you interact with the project, when you don't find it, you can't move forward, especially when you're a beginner

Comment: Well, literally the first command there is `$ django-admin startproject mysite` which creates a new Django project with basic structure and a `manage.py` file : )

Comment: Show us an example of a "Django sample" you have downloaded. Probably they are supposed to be apps which you integrate into your own project.

Comment: Edit your Q to add contents of Readme.rst!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running,

```
python setup.py install
```

You could learn more about installing and how to integrating 
django-zinnia in the link [here](http://docs.django-blog-zinnia.com/en/develop/getting-started/install.html)

I'm afraid you need to have an existing project for this application.

You could start one by running

```
django-admin startproject project_name
```

Comment: several files have been generated in C:/Python/lib after the execution of ( python setup.py install ), I just don't know how to run the project so I could view it in my browser

Comment: it needs to install before running, go look in C:/Python and look for executable such as manage.py files

Comment: I can see all what it takes to run a project (models, templates, urls, ... ), but there is no manage.py

Comment: can you share what do you see? from here I could help no better than this.

Comment: C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\django_blog_zinnia-0.19.dev0-py3.6.egg\zinnia

Comment: You could edit the question and add a link to screenshot of what you see..

Comment: 05/23/2017  03:04 PM    <DIR>          .
05/23/2017  03:04 PM    <DIR>          ..
05/23/2017  03:04 PM    <DIR>          admin
05/23/2017  03:04 PM               785 apps.py
05/23/2017  03:04 PM             4,853 breadcrumbs.py
05/23/2017  03:04 PM             4,664 calendar.py
05/23/2017  03:04 PM             7,108 comparison.py
05/23/2017  03:04 PM             1,125 context.py
05/23/2017  03:04 PM               192 context_processors.py
05/23/2017  03:04 PM            15,024 feeds.py

Comment: Well, I'll keep fighting till I figure something out, thanks Zaid

Comment: I have included a link to django-zinnia... hope you get what you were looking for

Comment: check my answer

Comment: it seems interesting, I'll dig deeper into the documentation of the app, thanks a lot.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, could you do me a favour and mark the answer as selected, then?